# SQL Server String extract based on pattern

Tags: sql-server, regex

I have string data in the following format:

```
MODELNUMBER=Z12345&HELLOWORLD=WY554&GADTYPE=PLA&ID=Z-12345
/DTYPE=PLA&ID=S-10758&UN_JTT_REDIRECT=UN_JTT_IOSV
```

and need to extract IDs based on two conditions

1. Starting after a pattern  `&ID=`
2. Ending till the last character or
3. if it hits a `&` stop right there.

So in the above example I'm using the following code:

`SUBSTRING(MyCol,(PATINDEX('%&id=%',[MyCol])+4),(LEN(MyCol) - PATINDEX('%&id%',[MyCol])))`

Essentially looking the pattern &id=% and extract string after that till end of the line. Would anyone advise on how to handle the later part of the logic ..

My current results are

```
Z-12345
Z-12345&UN_JTT_REDIRECT=UN_JTT_IOSV
```

What I need is

```
Z-12345
Z-12345
```

Comment: will this `S-15229` be always 7 characters

Comment: Should the second line in section "What I need is" = "S-10758"?  Currently both lines have same value "Z-12345".

Answer (score 17):

Try this

```
SUBSTRING(MyCol, (PATINDEX('%[A-Z]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',[MyCol])),7)
```

if you run into performance issues add the where clause below

```
-- from Mytable
WHERE [MyCol] like '%[A-Z]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```

maybe not the most elegant solution but it works for me.

[Correct syntax of PATINDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql)

Comment: I would like to add a caveat in case PATINDEX does not find the pattern, it defaults to 0, which might lead to unwanted strings being extracted.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one example how to do it:

```
select
    substring(d.data, s.s, isnull(nullif(e.e,0),2000)-s.s) as ID, 
    d.data 
from data d
cross apply (
    select charindex('&ID=', d.data)+4 as s
) s
cross apply (
    select charindex('&', d.data, s) as e
) e
where s.s > 4
```

This assumes there data column is varchar(2000) and the where clause leaves out any rows that don't have &ID=

The first cross apply searches for the start position, the second one for the end. The isnull+nulliff in the actual select handles the case where & is not found and replaces it with 2000 to make sure the whole string is returned.