# If string is in field text then get another part of the string

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL I have a field that has a lot of text in it.

I am trying to find a way to get text from the field if it contains certain words.

An example:

```
textField = 'This is the value for your spaceID=12345678'

textField = 'This is the value for your typeID=43254364'
```

So if the `textField` contains `spaceID` I want to return the value for it

If `textField` like `spaceID` then return 12345678

I am just not sure how to return the value of that ID.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server String extract based on pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28311360/sql-server-string-extract-based-on-pattern)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi i think thoses example can help you :

```
declare @value varchar(400)

SET @value = 'This is the value for your spaceID=12345678'
select @value, CHARINDEX('=',@value,1), SUBSTRING(@value,CHARINDEX('=',@value,1) + 1 ,10)
where @value like '%spaceID%'
```

And see thoses different link :

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017
  -[SQL Server String extract based on pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28311360/sql-server-string-extract-based-on-pattern)

Comment: This script fully rely on "=", it will not return expected result if some reason there is another occurrence of "=" .

Comment: @PawelCzapski thx you . Yes it’s just example they have to adapt this with they data

Answer (score 1):

You can use `substring()` :

```
select substring(textField, charindex('spaceID=', textfield) + 8, len(textField))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `substring()`:

```
select substring(textfield, charindex('spaceID=', textfield) + len('spaceID='), 100)
from tablename
where textfield like '%spaceID=%'
```

Comment: this is more defensive answer, I like you used "len" instead hardcoding

Comment: i guess `spaceID=` is just a sample literal string, so the code should be flexible with any other string.

Comment: Yeap, still better use "spaceID=" than just "=", as this may occur in other places also.

Comment: Just to be on the safe side.