# How To Add White Space Between Text and Numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an ID column in my table which contains values like this:

```
D8565GL
PA8791AG
```

I want to add a white space to these values like this:

```
D 8565 GL
PA 8791 AG
```

How do I solve this using SQL Server?
Thank you

Comment: i do curious what have you tried? also, is the column a (n)varchar? if so, you can try [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39542027).

Comment: A complete question would describe whether this is a one-time update or one that must happen on the fly as well as a fully description of the domain of possible inputs. It's also potentially relevant to know whether this update will happen in Transact SQL vs a stand-alone `select/update` query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select concat(
    substring(ID, 0, patindex('%[0-9]%', ID)),
    ' ',
    substring(ID, patindex('%[0-9]%', ID), 4),
    ' ',
    substring(ID, patindex('%[0-9]%', ID) + 4, 2)
  )
from vehicles;
```

Quick fix I cooked [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/kEWZKb3N). It uses regex to find the 4 digits location and then just do substring to get the values.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that all your ID values follow a similar format of essentially `/[alpha]+[digit]+[alpha]+/` Despite that assumption, the code below is actually only relying on there being two transitions in the string where the character sequence switches between numeric to alphabetic and then again the opposite way. The order that happens (left to right) doesn't matter so effectively it also handles `/^[:alpha:]+[:digit:]+[:alpha:]*$/` and `/^[:digit:]+[:alpha:]+[:digit:]*$/` You can easily extend this pattern if necessary.

```
select *
from T 
    cross apply
    (values (stuff(ID,  patindex('%[A-Z][0-9]%', ID)  + 1, 0, ' '))) as v1(ID2)
    cross apply
    (values (stuff(ID2, patindex('%[0-9][A-Z]%', ID2) + 1, 0, ' '))) as v2(NewID);
```

If no pattern matches are found then it ends up adding a space character in the initial position. A simple `ltrim()` would clean that up.

https://dbfiddle.uk/d06S7YSG